# Do you use 'fare(food)' as a collective noun?

Tags: usage

Why not a plural form ***fares*** but ***fare***(line6)? Can it be used as a collective noun?

> The American paradox, in culinary terms, is that although foods from
> throughout the world are available, and often affordable, consistency
> and conservatism are also needed. At one end of the spectrum, people
> who are exposed to new foods through travel and those who crave new
> taste experiences have driven the rapidly expanding market for
> imported fruits, vegetables, and meat products, cheeses, and
> condiments. The growth in ethnic restaurants has far surpassed that of
> the restaurant industry as a whole in recent decades. A survey found
> that Italian, Mexican, Japanese (sushi), Thai, Middle Eastern, and
> Caribbean ***fare*** have grown most in popularity in recent years,
> while interest in French, German, Scandinavian, and soul food has
> declined. One of the most recent developments is the success of
> fast-casual ethnic restaurant chains, such as Chipotle, Curry in a
> Hurry, L&L Hawaiian Barbecue, Mama Fu’s, and Pho Hoa. Ninety-two
> percent of U.S consumers have eaten some form of ethnic food in the
> past three months (whether at home or from a restaurant). At the other
> end of the American continuum of cuisine, some people find
> considerable satisfaction in the uniformity of a meat-and-potatoes
> diet. A national trends survey found “plain” American food most well
> liked by respondents (66 percent).

[Food and Culture](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=N78aCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT42&lpg=PT42&dq=Thai,%20Middle%20Eastern,%20and%20Caribbean%20fare%20have%20grown%20most%20in%20popularity%20in%20recent%20years,%20while%20interest%20in%20French,%20German,%20Scandinavian,%20and%20soul%20food%20has%20declined.&source=bl&ots=81IKcDTWdD&sig=ACfU3U3xdpGiIAXJ9BKSD-3zoy2ddixIaQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJpKmfvan4AhWqJaYKHZp2BF8Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=Thai%2C%20Middle%20Eastern%2C%20and%20Caribbean%20fare%20have%20grown%20most%20in%20popularity%20in%20recent%20years%2C%20while%20interest%20in%20French%2C%20German%2C%20Scandinavian%2C%20and%20soul%20food%20has%20declined.&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no plural form, as "fare" in this particular sense (a range of food of a particular type) is **uncountable**.

See this entry from [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fare_1?q=fare):

[image]